# How automatically accept system alerts on iOS

Tags: ios, uialertview, cllocationmanager, uialertcontroller

I want to automatically accept system alerts (e.g. access location services, access camera, enable notifications) on behalf of the user. This is for my own testing purposes and would never be submitted to the app store so please don't comment on the ethics of doing this! Use of private APIs or other hacks would be fine for my purposes.

I want a solution that works solely within the app. No driving the app using external test harnesses, instruments, Xcode etc.

I was thinking I could swizzle UIAlert or UIAlertController methods and fake acceptance assuming Apple uses these classes internally for it's alerts. Has anyone tried this approach?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible to due Apple's restriction of system services. Only way I could think of getting around this is creating a jailbroken app so you have access to the entire system, and not just what Apple wants you to see. Interesting question.

Comment: There is a new method in XCTest called `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription:` which allows a test script to accept or deny a specific system alert.  It may be possible to access this at runtime by manually invoking the method from `XCTestCase`.  I was looking for the `XCTest` headers for iOS but could only find them for tvOS: https://github.com/neonichu/tvOS-headers/blob/master/XCTest/XCTestCase.h